# Function automatically called in some condition

Tags: angularjs

I have code like this：

```
<div class="row"
     ng-repeat="x in companies|orderBy:'id' ">
    <div class="col left" >
        <button ng-click="viewPublicId(x.id)">{{x.companyname}}</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col left">
        {{x.address}}
    </div>
    <div class="col left">
        {{x.telephone}}
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want to do is add a check: when companies.size=1, function viewPublicId is automatically called. How can I achieve that? Thanks.

**updated**: viewPublicId function:

```
$scope.viewPublicId = function viewPublicId(companyid) {
    var url = "http://7cf8d64c.tunnel.mobi/yii2-basic/web/index.php?r=restpublic/view&companyid=" + companyid;
    console.log("debug", url);
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function (response)
    {
    console.log("debug PublicId",response);
    if(response.length==33)
    $scope.publicids = null;
    else
    $scope.publicids = response;
    })
    .error(function (response)
    {
    console.log("debug PublicId",response);
    $scope.publicids = null;
    });

    $state.go('tabs.publicidlist');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you controller:

```
if ($scope.companies.length === 1) {
    $scope.viewPublicId();
}
```

If your `companies` could be changed dynamically, and you need to call the function everytime it changes, use `$watch`:

```
$scope.$watch('companies', function () {
    if ($scope.companies.length === 1) {
        $scope.viewPublicId();
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: thanks for your concerns. It's said "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Comment: check that your $scope.companies is declared.
````$scope.companies = [];````

Comment: @CozyAzure, I got it. thanks. Now comes another question: "$scope.viewPublichId is not a function" (I've updated post for viewPublicId function)

Comment: Hi, pay more attention even when copy pasting codes. Joy had a typo in his ``$scope.viewPublichId()``, where as your own code you wrote ``$scope.viewPublicId()``